# Como fazer um sistema de busca com react

Tags: javascript, react, algoritmo-de-busca

Gostaria de saber como que faço para criar um sistema de busca dentro do react tendo um input e outro botão de pesquisa, de preferencia usando react-router se tiver como fazer por ele.

Em particular estou tentando utilizando a tag Link, porem ela só funciona na primeira vez, nas outras ela muda a url, porem a tag Route continua igual, aparentemente não está atualizando o Route.

-main

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './style.css'
import Postings from './pages/Postings/index'
import Search from './pages/Search/index'
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import CreatePost from './pages/CreatePost'

export default class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        userId: '',
    }

    render() {
        const {userId} = this.state

        return (
            <main id='main'>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div id='subMenu'>
                        <h2>Busque uma postagem através do id de usuário de quem publicou</h2>
                        <input id='search' className='search' placeholder='ID de usuário' value={userId} onChange={(e) => this.setState({userId: e.target.value})}></input>
                        <Link className='searchStart' to={userId == '' ? '/' : `/posts/userId/${userId}`}>Pesquisar</Link>
                        <hr />
                        <h2>Crie uma nova postagem agora, apenas clique no botão abaixo e preencha o formulario</h2>
                        <Link className='createPosting' to={`/posts/create`}>Criar nova postagem</Link>
                    </div>

                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Postings} />
                        <Route exact path='/posts/userId/:userId' component={Search} />
                        <Route exact path='/posts/create' component={CreatePost} />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

-componente de pesquisa

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './style.css'
import api from '../../../../service/api'
import imgDelete from '../../../../img/delete.png'

export default class Postings extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    state = {
        postings: [],
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.loadPostings() 
    }

    loadPostings = async () => {
        const response = await api.get(`/posts?userId=${this.props.match.params.userId}`)
        this.setState({postings: response.data})
    }

    deletePost = (post) => {
        api.delete(`/posts/${post.id}`)
        alert(`Post foi deletado (simulação) - Post ID: ${post.id} / User ID: ${post.userId}`)
    }

    render() {
        const {postings} = this.state

        return (
            <div className='postings'>
                {
                    postings.map(post => {
                        return ( 
                            <div key={post.id} className='post'>
                                <img className='delete' onClick={(e) => this.deletePost(post)} src={imgDelete} />
                                <h3 className='userId'>ID de usuário: {post.userId}</h3>
                                <h2 className='title'>{post.title}</h2>
                                <hr />
                                <p className='body'>{post.body}</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Como disse, apenas gostaria de saber como faço um sistema de busca, parecido com o da imagem abaixo, estou utilizando o react-router pois ainda sou iniciante no react e é o que conheço atualmente, mas se houver outra maneira também tenho interesse.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Achei a resposta para isso, é apenas chamar a função padrão no React "componentDidUpdate()". Adicionar ela dentro da classe Postings.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.loadPostings()
}
```